# php check for a valid date, weird date conversions

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

Is there a way to check to see if a date/time is valid you would think these would be easy to check:

```
$date = '0000-00-00';
$time = '00:00:00';
$dateTime = $date . ' ' . $time;

if(strtotime($dateTime)) {
    // why is this valid?
}
```

what really gets me is this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

results in: "1999-11-30",

huh? i went from 0000-00-00 to 1999-11-30 ???

I know i could do comparison to see if the date is either of those values is equal to the date i have but it isn't a very robust way to check. Is there a good way to check to see if i have a valid date? Anyone have a good function to check this?

Edit:
People are asking what i'm running:
Running PHP 5.2.5 (cli) (built: Jul 23 2008 11:32:27) on Linux localhost 2.6.18-53.1.14.el5 #1 SMP Wed Mar 5 11:36:49 EST 2008 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: Try this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Comment: strtotime("0000-00-00 00:00:00") returns FALSE on a 32 bit system.
 strtotime("0000-00-00 00:00:00") returns -62169955200 on a 64 bit system.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#78362)

```
<?php
function isValidDateTime($dateTime)
{
    if (preg_match("/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) ([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/", $dateTime, $matches)) {
        if (checkdate($matches[2], $matches[3], $matches[1])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned here:  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45647

> There is no bug here, 00-00-00 means 2000-00-00, which is 1999-12-00,
>   which is 1999-11-30. No bug, perfectly normal.

And as shown with a few tests, rolling backwards is expected behavior, if a little unsettling:

```
>> date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2012-03-00'))
string: '2012-02-29'
>> date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2012-02-00'))
string: '2012-01-31'
>> date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2012-01-00'))
string: '2011-12-31'
>> date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2012-00-00'))
string: '2011-11-30'
```

Answer (score 2):

> echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
>
> results in: "1999-11-30"

The result of `strtotime` is 943920000 - this is the number of seconds, roughly, between the [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (base from which time is measured) to 1999-11-30.

There is a **documented [mysql bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=17123)** on `mktime(), localtime(), strtotime()` all returning this odd value when you try a pre-epoch time (including "0000-00-00 00:00:00"). There's some debate on the linked thread as to whether this is actually a bug:

> Since the time stamp is started from 1970, I don't think it supposed to
>   work in anyways.

Below is a function that I use for converting dateTimes such as the above to a timestamp for comparisons, etc, which may be of some use to you, for dates beyond "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

```
/**
 * Converts strings of the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" into php dates
 */
function convert_date_string($date_string)
{
    list($date, $time) = explode(" ", $date_string);
    list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(":", $time);
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $date);
    return mktime($hours, $minutes, $seconds, $month, $day, $year);
}
```

Comment: i tried date('Y-m-d', convert_date_string('0000-00-00 00:00:00')) but still gives the 1999 date

Comment: Found the PHP bug report on the odd behaviour of time-based functions in PHP for the 0000-00.. value. There is some debate on that thread as to whether it's actually a bug, as if people would ever want to calculate a date pre-1970!

Answer (score 1):

Don't expect coherent results when you're out of range:

cf [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

cf [Gnu Calendar-date-items](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Calendar-date-items.html#SEC116).html

> "For numeric months, the ISO 8601
> format ‘year-month-day’ is allowed,
> where year is any positive number,
> **month is a number between 01
> and 12**, and **day is a
> number between 01 and 31**. A
> leading zero must be present if a
> number is less than ten."

So '0000-00-00' gives weird results, that's logical!

---

> "Additionally, **not all
> platforms support negative timestamps,
> therefore your date range may be
> limited to no earlier than the Unix
> epoch**. This means that e.g.
> %e, %T, %R and %D (there might be
> more) and **dates prior to Jan
> 1, 1970 will not work on Windows, some
> Linux distributions, and a few other
> operating systems**."

cf [strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

---

Use [checkdate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) function instead (more robust):

> month:
> The **month is between 1 and 12 inclusive**.
>
> day:
> The day is within the allowed number of days for the given
> month. Leap year s are taken
> into consideration.
>
> year:
> The **year is between 1 and 32767 inclusive**.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to handle a date conversion without the time for a mysql date field, you can modify this great code as I did.
On my version of PHP without performing this function I get "0000-00-00" every time.  Annoying.

```
function ConvertDateString ($DateString)
{
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $DateString);
    return date ("Y-m-d, mktime (0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This version allows for the field to be empty, has dates in mm/dd/yy or mm/dd/yyyy format, allow for single digit hours, adds optional am/pm, and corrects some subtle flaws in the time match.

Still allows some pathological times like '23:14 AM'.

```
function isValidDateTime($dateTime) {
    if (trim($dateTime) == '') {
        return true;
    }
    if (preg_match('/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})(\s+(([01]?[0-9])|(2[0-3]))(:[0-5][0-9]){0,2}(\s+(am|pm))?)?$/i', $dateTime, $matches)) {
        list($all,$mm,$dd,$year) = $matches;
        if ($year <= 99) {
            $year += 2000;
        }
        return checkdate($mm, $dd, $year);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been just changing the martin answer above, which will validate any type of date and return in the format you like.

Just change the format by editing below line of script
strftime("10-10-2012", strtotime($dt));

```
<?php
echo is_date("13/04/10");

function is_date( $str ) {
    $flag = strpos($str, '/');

    if(intval($flag)<=0){
        $stamp = strtotime( $str );
    } else {
        list($d, $m, $y) = explode('/', $str);    
        $stamp = strtotime("$d-$m-$y");
    } 
    //var_dump($stamp) ;

    if (!is_numeric($stamp)) {
        //echo "ho" ;
        return "not a date" ;        
    }

    $month = date( 'n', $stamp ); // use n to get date in correct format
    $day   = date( 'd', $stamp );
    $year  = date( 'Y', $stamp );

    if (checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
        $dt = "$year-$month-$day" ;
        return strftime("%d-%b-%Y", strtotime($dt));
        //return TRUE;
    } else {
        return "not a date" ;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function is_valid_date($user_date=false, $valid_date = "1900-01-01") {
    $user_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($user_date));
    return strtotime($user_date) >= strtotime($valid_date) ? true : false;
}

echo is_valid_date("00-00-00") ? 1 : 0;    // return 0

echo is_valid_date("3/5/2011") ? 1 : 0;    // return 1
```

Comment: that would work for dates that are "recent", but if I have a date in the early ninety's it would always return false

Comment: @SeanDowney edited, which should return TRUE for your "date in the early ninety's".

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code to validate dates coming from ExtJS applications.

```
function check_sql_date_format($date) {
    $date = substr($date, 0, 10);
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date);
    if (!is_numeric($year) || !is_numeric($month) || !is_numeric($day)) {
        return false;
    }
    return checkdate($month, $day, $year);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

function is_date( $str ) {
    $stamp = strtotime( $str );

    if (!is_numeric($stamp)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $month = date( 'm', $stamp );
    $day   = date( 'd', $stamp );
    $year  = date( 'Y', $stamp );

    if (checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't work with some edge cases such as February 31st or April 31st. For example date("Y-m-d", strtotime("31.2.2012")) results in "2012-03-02" which passes the checkdate validation even though user didn't input a valid date.