# in PHP, how to check if the date_create return an valid date object?

Tags: php

```
date_create('sdfsdfdsfsd') //invalid
date_create('2010-07-30 08:03') //valid
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) it is simply an alias of [DateTime::__construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) which:

> Returns a new DateTime instance.
>   Procedural style returns FALSE on
>   failure.

Answer (score 2):

If the `date_create` function doesn't return a valid date object, it'll return `FALSE`.

A much more complicated alternative is to validate its parameter with Regex according to http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could validate first:

[php check for a valid date, weird date conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141315/php-check-for-a-valid-date-weird-date-conversions/141365#141365)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this covered right at the top of the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)?

```
<?php
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
if (!$date) {
    $e = date_get_last_errors();
    foreach ($e['errors'] as $error) {
        echo "$error\n";
    }
    exit(1);
}

echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

Comment: or:

`try{$d = new DateTime('blargh!!!');}catch(Exception $e){echo $e->getMessage();}`