# Why is strtotime() working differently on different servers?

Tags: php, date, timestamp

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$time = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
echo $time . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

$time = strtotime($time);
echo $time . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
```

On our development server, the second `$time` outputs nothing. A test with `var_dump()` reveals its value to be `false`. Which is fine. On a live server, I get `943920000`. A test with `var_dump()` shows that this is an integer.

Why?

Apparently [it is fairly common for dates of zero to come up as 30 November 1999](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141315/php-check-for-a-valid-date-weird-date-conversions). Why? And why on some servers and not on others?

Comment: It might be because of timezone difference or configuration on different servers?

Comment: Maybe not the best solution, but whats about checking for `$time == 0` before doing an conversion? Tell more about your setup (timezone configuration, PHP Version, ...)

Comment: @breiti. That's what I did in the end. And it seems to work. I was just wondering what's special about 30th November 1999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [PHP Manual page for `strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), we get the following:

> Returns a timestamp on success, FALSE otherwise.

Therefore it follows that on one of your servers, the call to `strtotime()` is failing.

So why would it fail? The answer to that is also on the same manual page:

> **Errors/Exceptions**
>
> Every call to a date/time function will generate a E_NOTICE if the time zone is not valid, and/or a E_STRICT or E_WARNING message if using the system settings or the TZ environment variable. See also date_default_timezone_set()

So it seems to me that your one server doesn't have it's timezone locale configured correctly.

All that said and done, I would suggest not using `strtotime()` for stuff like this, if possible. It is a bit of a clunky old function, and the newer PHP [datetime library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) provides much better/cleaner functionality. You can create a datetime object using it as follows:

```
$date = new DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

hope that helps.

Comment: [comments on PHP.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45647): "There is no bug here, 00-00-00 means 2000-00-00, which is 1999-12-00, which is 1999-11-30. No bug, perfectly normal."

Answer (score 1):

try

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");
```

before any strtotime call